NextAuth not be able to login with google: To confirm your identity, sign in with the same account you used originally
I'm encountering the following error in the terminal
[auth][error] OAuthAccountNotLinked: Another account already exists with the same e-mail address.

According to the NextAuth error documentation, this error occurs when an OAuth account is being linked to an existing account that has the same email. However, I've already deleted all the users from the users table in my database, and there shouldn't be any conflict.
Despite clearing the table, the error persists when attempting to authenticate via OAuth. I've also checked the accounts table to ensure there are no residual records that could be causing this issue.
I have also tried clearing session data, cookies, and revoking OAuth provider access, but the error still occurs.
Can anyone provide guidance on why this error might still be occurring, even after deleting all relevant records?
